# Program not running on mac PHP - Terminal - Arduino

Tags: php, macos, terminal, arduino, serial-port

So basically my bell program has to work on a mac computer now. i configured it an did the stuff. now the problem is that it is sending a value and there is a blink on the Arduino serial led but the led which is supposed to blink the number of times the bell has to ring does not blink. It works when i send value through ide or when i do it on windows. i tried to do it manually though terminal by typing `ECHO 2 > /dev/cu.usbmodem1411` and still it doesn't happen. If i do `screen /dev/tty.usbmodem1411 9600` and then type the number manually the light blinks.
Code:

```
<?php
include('database.php');
$usb_comPort = "/dev/cu.usbmodem1411";
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$time = date("H:i");
$time = trim($time);
$sql = "SELECT bell_amount FROM bell_db WHERE DATE_FORMAT(bell_time,'%H:%i') LIKE '$time'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($numRows == 0) {
  echo 'Error: Nothing found!';
} else {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $bellAmount = $row['bell_amount'];
  $runCommand = "ECHO " . $bellAmount . " > $usb_comPort";
  echo $runCommand;
  exec($runCommand);
}
?>
```

^^My program is in php. It sends value to Arduino through serial port which reads it and blinks a led those no. of times. I am using Xampp for apache and Mysql for database. So Whats happening? 
P.S.
I seriously didn't know how to accept answers people so when i got to know i accepted them.

Comment: Just a guess in the wild, the USB-ComPort is not attached to the mac, but to the arduino. So there's no way the signal gets to the arduino led.

Comment: @Christian it does work in other cases though

Comment: Don't you need the baud rate in the definition of `$usb_comPort`? Like: `$usb_comPort = "/dev/cu.usbmodem1411 9600";`

Comment: @mhopeng i did that still no change